# free() function without using any memory allocation functions

Tags: c, database, free

I am writing a code for student database and want to delete a string which contains roll no., name and marks. But i haven't used any structure or memory allocation functions earlier in the code. Can free function still be used to delete the string in the way i used, is there any way to delete that string without using malloc and calloc?

```
void del()                  `
{
    char *str;
    FILE *fp;
    char ch[20],ch1[20];
    fp=fopen("database.txt","a");
    printf("enter roll to be deleted:");
    scanf("%s",&ch1);
    while(fscanf(fp,"%s",ch)!=EOF)
{
    if(strcmp(ch,ch1)==0)
    {
    str=&"%s";
    free(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: This code won't compile.

Comment: `free()` should only be called on memory you allocated or on NULL

Comment: Have as many free as you have malloc / calloc (or realloc). None in this code and the `str=` line is broken.

Comment: @RingØ is there any way to delete that string, if i dont want to use malloc or calloc?

Comment: If the string is not dynamically allocated you have no reason to delete it (it's done automatically, either when a function dies, when the program process dies...)

Comment: @RingØ ok then i'll try that, thank you

Comment: Your `strcmp()` operation will cause a segfault most likely: use `strncmp` instead, and use a macro (i.e. `#define BUF_LEN (20)`) with your `ch/ch1` declarations, and as an argument to `strncmp`. Also, you never define `str`.

Comment: `"%s"` is a constant used in the program, just like `20`. You don't have to free the string literal, just like you don't free the `20`.

Comment: when asking a question about a runtime problem, as this question is doing, post a [mcve] otherwise there is little we can do to help you

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.  3) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding: `str=&"%s";`  and `scanf("%s",&ch1);` in C, an array reference always degrades to the address of the first byte of the array, so no need to use a leading `&`

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s",&ch1);` and `while(fscanf(fp,"%s",ch)!=EOF)` 1) when calling any of the scanf() family of functions, always check the returned value (in this case if != 1 then some error occurred) to assure the operation was successful. 2) when using the '%s' or '[...]' format specifiers, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer. The 'one less' is because that input specifiers will always append a NUL byte to the input. This avoids any buffer overflow (undefined behavior) which could lead to a seg fault event

Comment: there is nothing in the posted code to let the user know that they are expected to enter the same string (at least 2 if not more) multiple times

Comment: regarding: `str=&"%s";
    free(str);`  the pointer `str` is being set to point to some literal array in read-only memory.  That is NOT something that can be passed to `free()`

Comment: you might want to look at `mmap()` for that file, the current code is expecting each record in the 'database' to only contain the one field.  This can be corrected by inputting the other fields during that call to `fscanf()`

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the `free()` man page (type `man 3 free`):

> The free() function frees the memory space pointed to by ptr, which must have been returned by a previous call to malloc(), calloc() or realloc(). Otherwise, or if free(ptr) has already been called before, undefined behavior occurs.

So calling `free` on a statically allocated is undefined (i.e. you can not assume anything, it might do something, do nothing, crash, destroy the Earth, etc.)